# Elastice Search Query doesn't return all the data consistently via Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Here is my ES Index :-

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "template_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "tag": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "tool_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "test_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "metric_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "stats": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "baseline_value": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "computed_value": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "deviation": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "min_metric_value": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "max_metric_value": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "tool_result_tag": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "metric_result": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "metric_failure_message": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "result_analyzer_executed": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run Query on two fields like below :-

```java
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

// Query to fetch list of metrics for given testId and toolName
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("test_id", testId)) // test_id from Index
        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("tool_name", toolName)); // tool_name from Index
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
searchSourceBuilder.size(100);
```

When I run code with different set of "test_id" and "tool_name" It provides all the result sometimes and sometimes no result at all. If I run the same as DSL Query, It provides all the results from the Index.

Can anyone tell me why ES is behaving like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get some result and no results on the same test I'd and tool name or different? Did you tried running the same query manually against Elasticsearch REST API?